# How should I link-back to a website's landing page?

Tags: website-design, navigation, landing-page

My client would like to include a link back to his landing page ([Lawyer Jump Page](http://mikesuarezlaw.com/)) in case a user mistakenly clicks to the wrong website link (either Divorce Law or Personal Injury Law).

He understands that the browser's back button serves this function but would still like an in-page solution.

How should I link back to the landing page while minimally altering the design?  I was thinking about a **banner fixed to the top of the web site**?  Should it only display if users are coming from the landing page?  (I.e.  It won't have a link to the landing page if they visit the divorce or injury page directly from a web search)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your pages, a simple solution would be to have a top section just devoted to a link back to the main page which allows the user to quickly navigate back to the lawyer jump page. My [company's creative wing's sit](http://www.aditilitehouse.com/)e has this as shown below

[image]

The only time this link will not be available at the top is when he is the Lawyer jump page since there is no point in relinking back to itself and the logo serves the purpose. However do keep this link even when the user lands on Divorce law or Personal injury page from a search engine since it will allow him to jump to the Lawyer jump page as needed.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be trying to solve a problem without any indication that it is a problem.  You should **do some ux-testing to see if it actually is a problem** for your users, before you spend time complicating your interface to solve it.

In many situations, people use tabbed browsing to open up a new site in a new tab, and so don't ever need to navigate back.  That is just an example, but there are many ways in which this may not be needed at all.

That said, if you do need it, I would have a **small header visible on all sites** (including your main site) with navigation to maintain consistency among sites.

Answer (score 0):

**Why change the navigation?**
For one thing, your top nav appears to be a permanent navigational tool, but then it completely changes upon click. That's very disorienting for the user.

**Supplement with a breadcrumb**
Assuming you fix that issue (if you agree that it's an issue), you can supplement the top nav in subsequent pages with a breadcrumb: 
<kbd>Personal injury</kbd> > <kbd>Injury info</kbd> > <kbd>An even deeper page</kbd>